# Conditional formatting is not working if all in the selected range are blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I trying to apply conditional formatting on selected cells (A2:C2) with condition that if all aren't filled all selected cells must be in color red, once they all are filled then the color should be white.

I am using Google sheets, formula used is

[image: formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `custom formula` within CF

```
=COLUMNS($A2:$C2)-COUNTBLANK($A2:$C2)<>COLUMNS($A2:$C2)
```

Comment: With this, if I enter in one of the cells with i n range then all cells formatting goes white, it only gives red color when all are blank, the entire range should be red if any one cell in the range is blank.

Comment: Can you try the updated answer...

Comment: yes, thank that works perfectly. :), would it be possible to explain what the formula is doing exactly?

Comment: sure.. within the example we have 3 columns A:C and I am also counting the blank cells -> 3-3<>3 `TRUE` (will mark it red) ; 3-2<>3 `TRUE` (will mark it red) ; 3-1<>3 `TRUE` (will mark it red) ; 3-0<>3 `FALSE` (will be white) ; `<>=Not Equal To`